# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Rails using JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm applying input from users to generate location markers on a Google Map.

In my region > show view I have the following, in Slim:

```
.container-fluid
 .row
   -@region.locations.each do |location|
    #region-banner.banner[data-region-name="#{@region.name.downcase}" data-lat="#{location.lat}" data-lng="#{location.lng}"]
javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.regions);
```

Then in my region.js file I have:

```
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

app.regions = () => {
 function init() {
   startGoogleMap();
 }
 var mapElement = document.getElementById('region-banner');
 const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name');
 const latSpot = mapElement.getAttribute('data-lat');
 const lngSpot = mapElement.getAttribute('data-lng');

 const markersByRegion = {
   regionName: [
     {
       position: (latSpot, lngSpot),
       title: '<%=@region.location.name%>'
     }
   ]
 };
 let startGoogleMap = () => {
   let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('region-banner'), {
     zoom: 3,
     minZoom: 3,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
     styles: mapStyle
   });

   let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   markersByRegion[regionName].forEach(({ position, ...opts }) => {
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       ...opts,
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(...position),
       map
     });
     bounds.extend(marker.position);
   });

   map.fitBounds(bounds);
 };

 return init();
};
```

My thought process was to grab the element by the ID, from the element get the three attributes, create a variable using the attributes, and then iterate through to apply the attributes coming from data-lat and data-lng.

However I end up with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined on the section for markersByRegion[regionName].forEach(({ position, ...opts }) => {

Comment: `markersByRegion[regionName]` should just be `markersByRegion.regionName`.  Or you need to change your `markersByRegion` to have a key per `regionName`, but since it's `const` I'm assuming you don't want to

Comment: well that resolves the error but not an overall issue with displaying data